# why is my validation program not working?

Tags: python

```
import re

name = input("what is your name:\n")
    
def validation():
    valid = True
    while valid:
        pw = input("what is the password:\n")
        if pw == name:
            print("password cannot be your name")
            valid = True
        elif len(pw) < 8 or len(pw) > 21:
            print("password wrong size")
            valid = True
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",pw):
            print("password needs a number")
            valid = True
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",pw):
            print("password needs a lower case letter")
            valid = True
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",pw):
            print("password needs upper case letter")
            valid = True
        elif not re.search("[¬`!£$%^&*()-_+=~{[}]:;@,<>.?/|\]",pw):
           print("password needs a special character")
           valid = True
        elif re.search("[/s]",pw):
            print("NO SPACES")
            valid = True
        else:
            print("your password is valid")
            valid = False
    return pw
def main():
    validation()



main()
```

even when you put a symbol it says a special character is needed

Comment: Please use the code block feature in the wysiwyg or indent code text so it is properly formatted.

Comment: @HamzsAbdaoui How do you know that this is the original indentation?

Comment: @Matthias: Look at the source in the edit history. It was indented just fine, but not formatted as code. So the regular text formatting mashed it all together.

Comment: @FredLarson OMG, I didn't see that "source" button since over 8 years.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the characters in the RE for your special character check are actually special to regular expressions, and must be escaped. The one character you did escape, the close bracket for the RE, should not have been escaped.

Not taking the time to figure out which characters really need to be escaped, I just escaped them all and it seems to work:

```
re.search("[\¬\`\!\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\~\{\[\}\]\:\;\@\,\<\>\.\?\/\|]",pw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another thing: You would need to use `re.search("[\s]",pw)` instead id `re.search("[/s]",pw)` to avoid the error.